# Delta between two dates in Excel return negative number

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date, delta

I have a script to return the days difference between today's date and a date in an Excel file.

For some reason, for dates that are single numbered, I get a negative number.

**For example:**

```
Date : num days diffrence from today

4/7/2019 : -72 (wrong)

5/7/2019 : -42 (wrong)

20/8/2019 : 63 (correct)

30/6/2019 : 12 (correct)
```

*The results are true to the day posting this question `(17/6/2019)`*

I checked the rest of the 100 dates in my Excel files, and this behavior only happens on single numbered dates. For example: 5/7/2019 (July 5th 2019) or 3/10/2019 (October 3rd 2019).

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

file_name = pd.read_excel (r'Changes log.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(file_name, columns= ['Due Date'])

today = pd.Timestamp.today()
df['Due Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Due Date'])
delta = (df['Due Date'] - today).dt.days
print(delta)
```

Note: `df['Due Date`] contains the dates in the Excel file. Which are formatted by `%d/%m/%Y`

Any help would be great

Comment: I think in first 2 cases it defaults to US date format of MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: @IcedLance It does indeed, you can verify with `print(pd.to_datetime("4/7/2019").month)` which prints `4`. For `print(pd.to_datetime("20/8/2019").month)` it's `8`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the argument `dayfirst=True`:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Changes log.xlsx')
df.columns = ['Due Date']

today = pd.Timestamp.today()
df['Due Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Due Date'], dayfirst=True)
delta = (df['Due Date'] - today).dt.days
print(delta)
```

---

Example with data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['4/7/2019', '5/7/2019', '20/8/2019', '30/6/2019']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

delta = (df['Date'] - pd.Timestamp.today()).dt.days
```

Output

```
0    16
1    17
2    63
3    12
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't fix it

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, because looking at your example data, it did fix it. @DanielBeilin. I made an edit of your code, could you copy and paste exactly my code and try that?

Comment: Turns out the issue was caused by the formatting in Excel, the code itself works.

I changed the sorting of the cell and now everything seems to work! Thanks!
@Efran

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. Good luck with Python and Pandas. And dont forget to [accept as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if my answer helped you :) @DanielBeilin

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `format` argument of the [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) method.

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y”)
```

Full example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['4/7/2019', '5/7/2019', '20/8/2019', '30/6/2019']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
delta = (df['Date'] - pd.Timestamp.today()).dt.days
print(delta)
```

Outputs:

```
0    16
1    17
2    63
3    12
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: When I pass the `format="%d/%m/%Y"` argument I get an error:
`ValueError: time data datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 9, 0, 0) does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)`

Comment: That error looks like the stored value is already a `datetime`. If this is the case, you probably need to handle each datatype separately. I would look into the [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method

Comment: Turns out the issue was caused by the formatting in Excel, the code itself works.

I changed the sorting of the cell and now eveything seems to work! Thanks!